# Why would post action print code as print strings and not results? (php)

Tags: php, output

This *is* for school, so if you don't want to help me- I'm warning you ahead of time.

I have this code in an html page, that references a page called dieRoller.php:

```
<form method="post" action="dieRoller.php">
<label>Input how many sides your die has:</label>
<input type="numberInput" id="numberInput" name="numberInput" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

This is dieRoller.php:

```
<?php

$numberInput = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "numberInput");
$answerNum = rand(1,numberInput);

print " You've rolled a: " $answerNum;

?>
```

This is probably the stupidest question on planet earth, but I cannot figure out why, when I submit this form, my results are literally a text file of dieRoller.php, and not the print output? I've scoured. I don't get it.

Thank you, in advance for your help.

Comment: Is this on a server that has php installed?

Comment: It's on a tested install of xampp....

Comment: Are you sure other PHP files run? Is PHP loaded with Apache? Also, `numberInput` is not a [valid `input` type](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-input-element.html#attr-input-type).

Comment: forget `$` in  `$answerNum = rand(1,$numberInput);`..???

Comment: @ajp15243- I'm going to test another one right now. It worked yesterday, but I should have tested it first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have following mistake.

You forget to adding `$` sign for php variable inside `rand` function.

**Replace**

```
$answerNum = rand(1,numberInput);
```

**with**

```
$answerNum = rand(1,$numberInput);
```

Comment: Thank you for that Dipesh. I saw your comment and fixed it! :)

Comment: @orchd you should accept answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Your dieRoller should look like this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['numberInput'])){
echo rand(1,$_POST['numberInput']);
}
?>
```

Comment: That is much more elegant than what I have, certainly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The two typos in your code are corrected below and the corrected code works when tested:

```
$answerNum = rand(1,$numberInput);

print " You've rolled a: " .$answerNum;
```